# Gulp Serve Error: Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, symlink

Tags: sharepoint-framework, nodejs

I am following the instructions in this guide. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part

The only difference is that I installed yo locally. When I run "gulp serve", https://localhost:5432/workbench is launched in the browser and I get the following error

> Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, symlink 'H:\My
>   Documents\VSCODE\simple-spfx-webpart\node_modules\@microsoft\sp-webpart-workbench'
>   -> 'H:\My Documents\VSCODE\simple-spfx-webpart\temp\workbench-packages\@microsoft_sp-webpart-workbench'
>       at Object.fs.symlinkSync (fs.js:1014:18)
>       at WorkbenchPage._getUrlForPackagePath (H:\My Documents\VSCODE\simple-spfx-webpart\node_modules\@microsoft\sp-webpart-workbench\lib\api\WorkbenchPage.js:166:17)
>       at WorkbenchPage._generateWorkbenchPageContent (H:\My Documents\VSCODE\simple-spfx-webpart\node_modules\@microsoft\sp-webpart-workbench\lib\api\WorkbenchPage.js:33:39)
>       at WorkbenchPage.handleWorkbenchRequest (H:\My Documents\VSCODE\simple-spfx-webpart\node_modules\@microsoft\sp-webpart-workbench\lib\api\WorkbenchPage.js:25:51)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (H:\My Documents\VSCODE\simple-spfx-webpart\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (H:\My Documents\VSCODE\simple-spfx-webpart\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
>       at Route.dispatch (H:\My Documents\VSCODE\simple-spfx-webpart\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (H:\My Documents\VSCODE\simple-spfx-webpart\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at H:\My Documents\VSCODE\simple-spfx-webpart\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
>       at Function.process_params (H:\My Documents\VSCODE\simple-spfx-webpart\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
>       at next (H:\My Documents\VSCODE\simple-spfx-webpart\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
>       at _setJSONResponseContentTypeMiddleware (H:\My Documents\VSCODE\simple-spfx-webpart\node_modules\@microsoft\gulp-core-build-serve\lib\ServeTask.js:120:9)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (H:\My Documents\VSCODE\simple-spfx-webpart\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at trim_prefix (H:\My Documents\VSCODE\simple-spfx-webpart\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
>       at H:\My Documents\VSCODE\simple-spfx-webpart\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
>       at Function.process_params (H:\My Documents\VSCODE\simple-spfx-webpart\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)

The command line log is shown in this image.
[image]

node version is 8.10.0
npm version is 5.6

Please advice. This is not the first time I am building spfx webparts. This is the first time I am getting this error.

Comment: Try to run console with admin privileges

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. That did not work. I also reinstalled node with 8.12 LTS version to see if that could fix but it did not. The sad part is that I cannot use any of the docker images because I am running 32bit windows.

Comment: In that case, I think you have to install yo locally because it's the only difference from official guidance.